# Plotly bubble map resize markers on zoom

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Python Plotly bubble map where each marker's diameter must correspond to a real-world distance. Is it possible for Plotly to dynamically resize markers on a bubble map when zooming in/out? Specifically, I'd like to make the markers bigger when zooming in and smaller when zooming out.

Here's the current behaviour in [Plotly's bubble map documentation](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-maps/):

Zoomed out
[image]

Zoomed in
[image]

As you can see, the markers remain the same size on the screen regardless of zoom.

Comment: The reason it does not change when zoomed in is because the maximum size is set to 20 by default. By increasing it to 20 or more, it will work with zooming. You can try this. `size_max=100`

Comment: If that's the case, then why don't the tiny markers with sizes less than 20 zoom either?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it well. The maximum bubble display limit is 20, so if you change it to 100, for example, the bubble will get bigger. Please add a setting and check it.

Comment: I added the setting and the bubbles got bigger, but they still don't resize when I zoom in

Comment: @AndiQu Did you figure this out?